# How to copy/paste in Gnome-Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, clipboard

After highlighting text at the command line in Gnome-Terminal with my mouse and then either (1) right-clicking to copy and paste or (2) center-clicking to paste, nothing has been copied.  I can copy fine in windows of any other Linux application and paste that material into the command line, but if I try to then copy and paste something from the command window, only the most recent non-command-window text that I copied will be pasted.

Answer (score 5):

Try highlighting text in gnome-terminal and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy it. Similarly, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> should paste text into gnome-terminal.

The idea is that we need the <kbd>shift</kbd> key too because at the command line, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is used to abort the currently running process.

Comment: This does not work for me, and it is **super frustrating!**. When pasting (with the proposed method or with any other usual method "know to men", what's being pasted is some previous text that was copied into the clipboard, seemingly from a gVim window.

Is there an explicit way to config this (RedHat 6.6 / GNOME 2.28.2 / GMONE Terminal 2.31.3, running in a remote VM window under Win10).